# Need to connect DB2 database using unix shell script

Tags: unix, db2

Need to connect to DB2 database by using unix shell script
I am using QMF tool to run DB2 queries everytime. Now i need to connect this through shell script.
DSN name --GM2P
DB name-- DPPRICMG
table name--item
Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.
can anyone please answer this ASAP.
Thanks

Comment: is db2 running on the unix box?

Answer (score 1):

In order to run the script properly you must be cataloged the remote database as this:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node NODE1 remote ip.ip.ip.ip server 50000
db2 catalog database mydb1 at node NODE1 authentication server
```

Then you can use this script to issue any sql you want:

```
db2 connect to mydb2 user username using password
db2 "update bla bla bla "
db2 connect reset
```

Note that if you are using DB2 for z/OS, then cataloging will be a bit different.